# In excel, what is 'Automatic' as a font colour? Behaves as black does, even on black cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, fonts, colors

In open office, the 'automatic' font colour option puts a light font in dark cells and vice versa.

Excel has the font colour 'automatic' available, but it appears to be exactly the same as just choosing 'black'.

Or am i mistaken?
Does it do something else that i haven't yet noticed?

Thanks!
Mike

Comment: In Excel, the fill and font Automatic color is black.

Answer (score 1):

"Automatic" means "Black" in Excel (rather useless, but that's it).

It's actually announced already in the Format Cells dialog, tab Font.

The following screenshot is taken for a cell where the fill color is black:

[image]